# django admin - custom action template

Tags: python, django, admin

Im trying to add a custom action to django app, where i can redirect to a `html (pdf)` page i created.

currently the `html` page only shows 1 result, What im trying to do is to show as many as `objects` i selcet from the `action` bar in django admin. here is my code.. `admin.py`

```
def print_pdf(modelAdmin, request, queryset, **kwargs):
    from django.template.loader import get_template
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
    from calculator.models import Transaction
    from xhtml2pdf import pisa
    
    chp = []
    for f in queryset:
        chp.append(f.chp_reference)

    for q in range(len(queryset)): # here im trying to know how many times to iterate based on how many qs selected

        transaction = get_object_or_404(Transaction, chp_reference=chp[1]) #im not sure what to do here
        template_path = 'report-pdf.html'
        context = {"transactions":transactions}
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='Application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename="report.pdf'
        template = get_template(template_path)
        html = template.render(context)
        pisa_status = pisa.CreatePDF(html, dest=response)
        if pisa_status.err:
            return HttpResponse('we had some errors' + html )
        return response

print_pdf.short_description = 'bulk pdf'

actions = [export_csv, print_pdf]
```

here is my code. I know its messed up, but i been trying to figure out to do this but im lost.
help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you provide more details?

Comment: once you return the first response you aren't going to go to the next iteration of the loop. You exit the `print_pdf` function at that time - its the nature of the return. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement

Comment: @AhmedI.Elsayed thanks for your concern, i've added some more details

Comment: @AMG thanks for your answer, but what do you suggest to make this iteration possible. should it be from the `html` side or it should be from here?

Comment: I'd personally have models for PrintBatchHeader, and PrintBatchDetail which would get populated during that admin task, then at end, redirect to a view of the PrintBatchHeader with all of the files listed and user can click on each one to download. I have no idea how, using Django, you'd get multiple new tabs opening from one request to a Django view. You can merge all the pdfs and deliver one large one - not clear if that would meet the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is the difference between the following snipppets.

```
def f(x)
    for i in range(x):
       return i ** 2

f(5) # 0 ONLY
```

```
def f(x):
   results = []
   for i in range(x):
       results.append(i ** 2)

   return results
```

You're returning after the first iteration, so the loop finishes after the first iteration.
You need to do the same as the second one, collect all results and return them at the end.

To illustrate what you want, this is based on your reply here. You can use something like

```
transactions = Transaction.objects.none()
for pk in chp:
    qs =  Transaction.objects.filter(chp_reference=i)
    transactions = transaction.union(qs)

return transactions
```

and improve it based on your needs

Comment: the issue that i dont know how to iterate through the list of chp_reference, so everytime it will return 1 index of the list  `transaction = get_object_or_404(Transaction, chp_reference=chp[1])`

Comment: what's chp ? a list of PKs ?